# Apache camel change value of tag

Tags: xml, apache-camel

Hi is it possible to change value of xml in apache camel route?

an example:

in:

```
<test>
    <name>test</name>
</test>
```

expected:

```
<test>
    <name>something</name>
</test>
```

how can I do this?

Comment: HI! I think to get a good answer you need to make clear what the purpose of this change is? Are you only updating a single element, or will you be updating a whole string of elements? Where are you getting the "something" from? Is it a fixed "a becomes b", or a list "a becomes b, c becomes d" or are you looking it up from somewhere? The most appropriate answer would depend on all these things.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Convert the xml into the corresponding Model object and then with the help of getter and setter methods you can change the value.
To write the convertor, you can either write your own convertor or you can Marshall the xml string.